# Size of Internet Explorer tile in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, live-tiles

While the tutorials say you can customise the size of tiles in Windows 8, this is not possible with the Internet Explorer tile. Because this is the tile I most often use I want it to be large, but the tile only has options for small or medium sizes.

Is there any way to make the IE tile large?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://superuser.com/questions/509777/why-there-is-no-option-to-make-ie-tile-larger

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

According answers.microsoft.com:

> I believe in the Final Release you cant change the size of the tile. Usually you can right click a tile and if you can change the size it will tell you at the bottom of the Start screen. I also tried moving it to a new column by itself and it still stayed the same size. So to answer your question I don't think there is a way to change the size of the Internet Explorer tile

[Resizing Internet Explorer 10 Tile on Metro Screen](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/resizing-internet-explorer-10-tile-on-metro-screen/e171322b-f546-44f2-9f71-71e04f8699cf)

Sorry man.